# In mongodb, what does it mean for an index to support a query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the [following definition](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-indexes-to-support-your-queries) about indexes in mongodb:

> An index supports a query when the index contains all the fields scanned by the query. The query scans the index and not the collection. Creating indexes that support queries results in greatly increased query performance.

Does it imply that an index is taken into account for a query execution ONLY if it contains ALL the fields requested by the query? So that, for example, if my query is searching for fields (a,b,c) and the only index in the collection was created on (b), it won't be used at all for the execution?

Comment: No ...  but the performance will increase dramatically if the index contains, in your case , a,b, and c

Comment: The quote is a recommendation, not a requirement. An index can be used even if a single field in the index prefix is in the query filter. As a rule of thumb, the more fields from a query are included in the index, the more "supportive"  the index is, apart from some edge cases (read about selectivity and multikey indices for details). In the extreme case the most supportive index contains all fields included in the projection. It's called covered query - mongo uses only index and does not fetch documents from the collection at all.

Comment: thanks to both for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the query.  From the [Query Plans](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-plans/) page:

> For a query, the MongoDB query optimizer chooses and caches the most efficient query plan given the available indexes.

Implicit in that statement is that the query you submit may not be the query that is executed; MongoDB may rewrite your query in multiple ways during the evaluation process.  Use [`cursor.explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to view the query plans considered by MongoDB and see which was chosen to execute your specific query (and why it was chosen).

The diagram below is from [version 4.0 of the Query Plans page](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/core/query-plans/) but I think it does a good job illustrating the query planner logic.

[image]